# Optimized method (for dataframes) to find time range overlaps with specified hour range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'll preface this by saying I have a method that works, but I'm looking to optimize and learn some more Pythonic methods of working on DataFrames.

The premise is as follows: I have multiple "visits" by a user to a certain location. These ranges could be any datetime to any datetime, but occur in chronological order:

```
Jan 1, 15:00 to Jan 1, 18:35 
Jan 3, 09:12 to Jan 5, 10:54 
Jan 5, 11:00 to Jan 6, 19:48
etc.
```

Now, I have these arrival and departure times in a `DataFrame`, and I'm looking to determine the total amount of time that is spent by the user between the hours of 8pm - 8am every day.

My current method is to apply a custom function on each row:

```
def find_8am_8pm_hours(t1, t2):
    if t1 > t2:
        raise Exception('t1 must be before t2')
    total = dt.timedelta(minutes=0)
    while t1 < t2:
        t1 += dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
        if (t1.time() < dt.time(8, 0)) or (t1.time() > dt.time(20, 0)):
            total += dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
    return total
```

and apply this on the DataFrame with:

```
df['Time Spent 8am-8pm'] = df.apply(lambda row: find_8am_8pm_hours(row['Arrival Time'], row['Departure Time']), axis=1)
```

I originally wrote the function with granularity at seconds, but it actually took some time to run on even very small data sets (a few seconds run time for a data set with only ~20 rows). Once I changed the approximation to minutes, the small data sets ran very quickly, but I imagine that with large data sets the algorithm would take a long time.

I know the `while` loop is the main culprit, but I couldn't think of any method that was more elegant. I had also considered if/else statements to handle specific cases of how times overlapped, but to handle 24+hr ranges, there would be 20 or more different types of cases to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me help you sort out some logic in your problems, the implementation part should be simple, either in Python/Pandas, or another programming language.

See the following diagram, I divided the window into 6 zones by `8AM` and `8PM` on 1-2 consecutive days(depends on the adjusted arrival-time and departure-time which I will discuss below):

```
            +---day1--+---day2--+
            |   z1    |   z4    |
            +---------+---------+<-- 8AM (a8)
            |   z2    |   z5    |
(p8) 8PM -->+---------+---------+
            |   z3    |   z6    |
            +---------+---------+
```

First we calculate the *delta_in_days* between two timestamps *t1* and *t2*,
each individual delta day will get you extra 12 hours into the final total.

Adding up the *delta_in_days* to the arrival-time, so that we can focus on a window which is within 1 day (24 hours) frame. Assume *ts* is the adjusted arrival-time and *te* is the departure-time, (Note: I originally defined them as start-time and end-time, thus named them *ts* and *te*) then

- ts = t1 + delta_in_days
- te = t2

Also set:

- `p8` the same day as `ts` but at 8PM
- `a8` the same day as `te` but at 8AM

Below list the possible cases with pseudo code:

**Case-1:**

*ts* and *te* in the same day - basically in *day2* and `p8 > a8`

```
if both in the same zone: z4(te < a8) or z6(ts > p8): 
    total = te - ts
else:
    total = max(0, te - p8) + max(0, a8 - ts)
```

**Case-2:**

*ts*, *te* in different days, if *te* in z6, then *ts* must be in z3. Remember, after the adjusted arrival-time, *ts* and *te* must be within the 24-hour window.

```
if te > p8 + 1day:
    total = (te - p8 - 1day) + (a8 - ts)
```

**Case-3:**

*ts*, *te* in different days, if *ts* in z1, then *te* must be in z4

```
if ts < a8 - 1day
    total = (a8 - 1day - ts) + (te - p8)
```

**Case-4:**

*ts* in [z2, z3] while *te* in [z4, z5]

```
total = min(a8, te) - max(p8, ts)
```

Code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

str="""Jan 1, 15:00 to Jan 1, 18:35 
Jan 3, 09:12 to Jan 5, 10:54 
Jan 5, 21:00 to Jan 6, 23:48
Jan 5, 23:00 to Jan 6, 20:48
Jan 5, 03:00 to Jan 6, 02:48
Jan 5, 10:00 to Jan 6, 05:48
Jan 5, 21:00 to Jan 6, 10:48
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(str)
     , sep='\s*to\s*'
     , engine='python'
     , names=['t1','t2']
)

for field in ['t1', 't2']:
    df[field] = pd.to_datetime(df[field], format="%b %d, %H:%M")

delta_1_day = pd.Timedelta('1 days')
# add 12 hours for each delta_1_day
ns_spent_in_1_day = int(delta_1_day.value*12/24)

# the total time is counted in nano seconds
def count_off_hour_in_ns(x):
    t1 = x['t1']
    t2 = x['t2']

    # number of days from t1 to t2
    delta_days = (t2 - t1).days
    if delta_days <= 0:
        return 0

    # add delta_days to start-time so ts and te in 1-day window
    # define the start-time(ts) and end-time(te) of the window
    ts = t1 + pd.Timedelta('{} days'.format(delta_days))
    te = t2

    # 8PM the same day as ts
    p8 = ts.replace(hour=20, minute=0, second=0)

    # 8AM the same day as te
    a8 = te.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0)

    # Case-1: te and ts on the same day
    if p8 > a8:
        if te < a8 or ts > p8:
            total = (te - ts).value
        else:
            total = max(0, (te - p8).value) + max(0, (a8 - ts).value)
    # Below ts and te all in different days
    # Case-2: te in z6
    elif te > p8 + delta_1_day:
        total = (te - p8 - delta_1_day + a8 - ts).value
    # Case-3: ts in z1
    elif ts < a8 - delta_1_day:
        total = (a8 - delta_1_day - ts + te - p8).value
    # Case-4: other cases
    else:
        total = (min(te, a8) - max(ts, p8)).value

    return total + delta_days * ns_spent_in_1_day

df['total'] = df.apply(count_off_hour_in_ns, axis=1)

print(df)

                   t1                  t2           total
0 1900-01-01 15:00:00 1900-01-01 18:35:00               0
1 1900-01-03 09:12:00 1900-01-05 10:54:00  86400000000000
2 1900-01-05 21:00:00 1900-01-06 23:48:00  53280000000000
3 1900-01-05 23:00:00 1900-01-06 20:48:00  35280000000000
4 1900-01-05 03:00:00 1900-01-06 02:48:00  42480000000000
5 1900-01-05 10:00:00 1900-01-06 05:48:00  35280000000000
6 1900-01-05 21:00:00 1900-01-06 10:48:00  39600000000000
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The method I am thinking of is to have the function break each single time range into 24 hour blocks (cut each time range by splitting at 8pm). For each 24 hour block, there can only be 3 categories:

1. Arrival before 8am, Departure before 8am (arrival ~ departure)
2. Arrival before 8am, Departure after 8am (arrival ~ 8am)
3. Arrival after 8am (0 hours)

[image: schedule]

Then simply add up each block of 24 hours back together.

This way the function is only doing several arithmetic operations at most, instead of iterating up to 60*60*24 = 86,400 times per day of data.